# Is there a way to tell how my reputation ranks among all users?

Tags: support, reputation

As my title states, is there a way I can determine how my reputation ranks among all users of a particular stack exchange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes

https://stackexchange.com/leagues

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @Randy No problem! Glad to help!

Comment: You can also view a list of all Stack Overflow users, sorted by reputation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149519/see-all-users-on-stack-overflow-sorted-by-reputation/149522#149522

Answer (score 1):

(This is the old way of doing it.  See everyone else's answers for a better method.)

You can get a rough by finding which page of users you are on, and dividing that by the total number of pages of users.

Right now you are on [page 30](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=30&tab=reputation) out of 9441.  So you are in the top .3% .  (I think that's how the math works.)

Comment: Or http://stackexchange.com/leagues

Comment: hehe +1 for "See everyone else's answers for a better method"

Answer (score 1):

See the [reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues). They are broken down by site, along with week, month, quarter, and year. You are shown on the top, and then other users sorted.