# See all users on Stack Overflow, sorted by reputation

Tags: support

Is it possible to see a list of all users on Stack Overflow, sorted by reputation (either in ascending order or descending order)? I'm wondering if Stack Overflow currently has any feature that makes this possible.

Comment: Uhhhh... you mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all)?

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort"

Comment: @meagar Yes, I'm ashamed of this question now. I lost a lot of reputation points as a result of posting it. :(

Comment: @AndersonGreen You don't lose reputation on Meta for downvotes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Yes.](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all)